# Rails 4 Bootstrap modal JavaScript not working despite trying everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I know there have been plenty of other posts like this but I have gone through a ton of them and still have not found a solution that works for me.

I have a modal that I am trying to open that I need to modify with JavaScript before it gets displayed to the user. Normally this would be a simple thing of setting the link on-click to call a JavaScript function to perform my actions and open the modal. However no matter what I try it will not open the modal, i just get

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
at open_report_legs_modal (pilot_actions.self-ef0bb7d….js?body=1:2)
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM315 2:252)
```

I have also tried opening the modal with the normal data-target and whatnot, then using JavaScript to execute on show.bs.modal but that does not work either, it just doesn't get triggered.

## My code

### Gem file entries

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'carmen-rails', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
```

### application.js requires section (No other relevant code in there, just some stuff for highlighting active nav bar links and initialising data-tables)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

### pilot_actions.js

```
function open_report_legs_modal(tourID, legID){
    $("#ReportLegModal").modal('show');
}
```

### The modal (pilot_actions/_report_leg.html.erb)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ReportLegModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ReportLegModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="ReportLegModalLabel">Report Leg</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= bootstrap_form_tag  url: pilot_actions_submit_tour_report_path do |f| %>

            <%= f.collection_select :tour, Tour.all, :id, :tour_name, {}, {class: 'disabled'}%>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="subject">Subject</label>

              <div class="col-md-8">
                <%= f.text_field :subject, placeholder: 'Enter the subject', class:'form-control', hide_label: true%>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="message">Message</label>

              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <%= f.text_area :message, placeholder: 'Enter message', class:'form-control', hide_label: true%>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
                <%= f.submit 'Send', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
              </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### The button that calls the javascript

```
<%= link_to '#', onclick: "open_report_legs_modal(#{@tour.id}, #{leg.id});" do %><% image_tag 'admin_images/validate.png', size:'25'%><% end%>
```

### Finally the modal is included on the same page as the button using

```
<%= render 'pilot_actions/report_leg' %>
```

I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

As well as the current setup, I've tried using //=require bootstrap and //=require bootstrap/modal, I've tried not using bootstrap sass and just including the normal bootstrap files and I've also tried using the bootstrap CDN, nothing has worked.

Comment: Try changing `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` to `//= require bootstrap` in application.js, that will include the entire bootstrap.js library.

Comment: @Aaron_H no joy :(

Comment: Still havn't had any luck fixing it. Going to be just doing it as a seperate page for now.

Comment: Still having issues with this, except this time it's with .dropdown instead of .modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY found the issue.

Apparently when I first created the application I added a script link for JQuery Datatables which included its own copy of JQuery which was breaking everything.